# Model Field added using custom SQL not detected by Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have added a field to my model. But I have added the field to the model in DB through a custom sql query(Alter Field). Now when I try to create other Migration files, Django creates migration for adding the field to that model in DB.
How to make django not do this?

I needed to do modify the collation of the field before adding a reference to another field.
Django Alter Field does Alter Table-Add Field,AlterTable-Add Reference
While I wanted Alter Table-Add Field,Modify Field Collation,AlterTable-Add Reference.
The custom sql query is written inside a migration file.

Comment: Why didn't you put that custom SQL into a migration? That's what they're for.

Comment: The custom SQL is in the migration file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) to create the field with the proper collation. When calling RunSQL use the `state_operations` argument to supply the state changes your SQL code made to keep Django up-to-date.

Here's an example from Django's documentation:

```
from django.db import migrations

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
            "ALTER TABLE musician ADD COLUMN name varchar(255) NOT NULL;",
            state_operations=[
                migrations.AddField(
                    'musician',
                    'name',
                    models.CharField(max_length=255),
                ),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let django create the migration that has creating that field as the only change. Then use the --fake flag to tell the database that migration has already been run.

`./manage.py migrate --fake [app] [migration number]`

This may cause problems if you're stepping through all your migrations at a later date or if you've written custom backwards code for your SQL migration.